# Getting clicked String from ListView

Tags: android, listview

i'm new to android and Its developing.i have Listview .when i press the item of it.i want to show its name-**String name**.how do i do ? please find below the code i used.there im getting myItem in Toast values such as 0,1,2,3... instead of String names. please find below the code snippet.

```
menu2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {


                     String selectedFromList = String.valueOf(menu2.getItemAtPosition(arg2));



                        ImageView imgbtn2 = (ImageView) arg1
                                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        Object item = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                        final String myitem = item.toString();

                            imgbtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method




                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),myitem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                }
                            });
```

Comment: You should move the ImageView in getView method of the adapter and add a separate onClickListener to it.

Comment: @Atul O Holic can you post it as answer

Comment: @simmant i mean listView item's display names.here credit cards names.i want to get the name of it.im very sorry about my bad English

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String selectedFromList = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
```

Answer (score 1):

On Rehan's demand. ;-)

You should move the ImageView in getView method of the adapter and add a separate onClickListener to it.

Glad I was able to help. :)

Comment: please add your getView() method and I will edit that for you.

Comment: i dont have getView() method im sorry.

Comment: Toast.makeText(getActivity(),myitem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); this line myitem im getting interger string values.i want String names of that please help me

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is you entire requirement and also post other codes of yours. Like what is menu2 for example?

Comment: is displaying credit cards and when i press the item of the ListView i want to display name of  purticular credit card in toast

Comment: and where is this name stored?

Comment: im getting names from web service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50152/discussion-between-atul-o-holic-and-rehan-k)

Comment: i have posted all my code.i couldnt located and i wasnt accepted to chat.thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To get your item:

```
String item = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
```

Comment: i have tried it but didnt work.im getting interger 1,2,3 instead of String

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get some from your list view item than its better go with the costume listview,
In that you can handle all the event of component of your costume listview in **getView()** method for more follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) url